# Logging in via a script to a remote server and execute a set of commands

Tags: bash, command-line, ssh

How can I login to a remote server and execute a set of commands then when done logout and continue my script?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't put Perl as a keyword unless you have a Perl question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ssh can be used to execute a command, rather than start a remote interactive login shell. For example:

```
ssh user@host ls
```

Will log into host and execute the `ls` command.

You can use this inside a bash script as normal:

```
#!/bin/bash

# do local commands

ssh user@host "ls; grep something file.txt; copy a b"

# do more local commands
```

From ssh's man page, the exit status will be the exit status of the remove command or 255 if an error occurred.

Comment: A few options: (1) place the commands in a separate file, use `scp` to copy the commands to the remote server, and run it or (2) put the commands into a variable inside the bash script and just run it as `ssh user@host "$COMMAND"`. You could read from a file into  COMMAND rather than have it all inline: `COMMAND=$(cat remote_cmds.sh)`

Comment: Why these aren't working: ssh user@domain.com "EEEEE='eeeesssse'
echo '$EEEEE'
echo \"$EEEEE\""

Comment: @emurad: You need to separate the commands with semicolons and you should reverse double and single quotes to keep the local shell away from `$EEEEE`: `ssh user@domain.com 'EEEEE='eeeesssse';echo "$EEEEE";echo "$EEEEE"'`

Comment: I followed your first suggestion and it worked very well (scp). Thanks.

Comment: Alternatively, separating the commands by newlines would work, too. Not sure how you can use this in perl, though.

Comment: this command asks for a password, how to specify password also in command line???

Answer (score 1):

Small variation with easier code formatting using `ssh` and `bash -s`:

```
echo '
globchar="*"
ls -1d $globchar
ls -ld $globchar
' |
ssh user@host "bash -s --"
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, you can use `ssh`. However, if you're running a script, you may want to setup `ssh` to login without a password. You can do that by setting up a public/private key via the [ssh-keygen](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen) command. Also change the permission of keyfiles (id_rsa, id_rsa.pub) as 600 for public key and 400 for private key for security of modification. chmod 600 id_rsa.pub ;chmod 400 id_rsa

On your system, you run `ssh-keygen` to generate the public and private keys. On Unix/Linux/Mac, these sit in the `$HOME/.ssh` directory. (Keep the passphrase blank!). Then, you want to create a file called `authorized_keys` on the remote machine under the `$HOME/.ssh` directory and copy your public key there.There is no need of generating encryption keys on remote m/c.

Now, when you do `ssh` or `scp` to the remote machine, you don't have to give the password.